# Can I reflect messages out of a Haskell program at runtime?

Tags: haskell, reflection, monads

I’m writing a program that validates a complex data structure according to a number of complex rules. It inputs the data and outputs a list of messages indicating problems with the data.

Think along these lines:

```
import Control.Monad (when)
import Control.Monad.Writer (Writer, tell)

data Name = FullName String String | NickName String
data Person = Person { name :: Name, age :: Maybe Int }

data Severity = E | W | C   -- error/warning/comment
data Message = Message { severity :: Severity, code :: Int, title :: String }
type Validator = Writer [Message]

report :: Severity -> Int -> String -> Validator ()
report s c d = tell [Message s c d]

checkPerson :: Person -> Validator ()
checkPerson person = do
  case age person of
    Nothing -> return ()
    Just years -> do
      when (years < 0) $ report E 1001 "negative age"
      when (years > 200) $ report W 1002 "age too large"
  case name person of
    FullName firstName lastName -> do
      when (null firstName) $ report E 1003 "empty first name"
    NickName nick -> do
      when (null nick) $ report E 1004 "empty nickname"
```

For documentation, I also want to compile a list of all messages this program can output. That is, I want to obtain the value:

```
[ Message E 1001 "negative age"
, Message W 1002 "age too large"
, Message E 1003 "empty first name"
, Message E 1004 "empty nickname"
]
```

I could move the messages out of `checkPerson` into some external data structure, but I like it when the messages are defined right at the spot where they are used.

I could (and probably should) extract the messages from the AST at compile time.

But the touted flexibility of Haskell made me thinking: can I achieve that **at runtime**? That is, can I write a function

```
allMessages :: (Person -> Validator ()) -> [Message]
```

such that `allMessages checkPerson` would give me the above list?

Of course, `checkPerson` and `Validator` **need not** stay the same.

I can almost (not quite) see how I could make a custom `Validator` monad with a “backdoor” that would run `checkPerson` in a sort of “reflection mode,” traversing all paths and returning all `Message`s encountered. I would have to write a custom `when` function that would know to ignore its first argument under some circumstances (which ones?). So, a kind of a DSL. Perhaps I could even emulate pattern matching?

So: can I do something like this, how, and what would I have to sacrifice?

Please feel free to suggest any solutions even if they do not exactly fit the above description.

Comment: This is a pretty tough problem in general, essentially you're wanting to write a static analysis tool for your DSL.  You could write such a DSL in Haskell using free monads pretty easily, actually, but performing the analysis to pull out all possible messages, however that's going to be difficult since a message's value could be determined solely at runtime.  If you limit your `title`s and `code`s using simple sum data types then it'd be a bit easier, but you still have the problem that some values could be only determined by runtime values.

Comment: @bheklilr I hope my answer blows your mind. =)

Comment: @DanielWagner it does a bit, yeah! I wouldn't have thought of that approach at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This kind of half-static analysis is basically exactly what arrows were invented for. So let's make an arrow! Our arrow will basically be just a `Writer` action, but one that remembers what messages it might have spit out at any given moment. First, some boilerplate:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}

import Control.Arrow
import Control.Category
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Prelude hiding (id, (.))
```

Now, the type described above:

```
data Validator m a b = Validator
    { possibleMessages :: [m]
    , action :: Kleisli (Writer m) a b
    }

runValidator :: Validator m a b -> a -> Writer m b
runValidator = runKleisli . action
```

There are some straightforward instances to put in place. Of particular interest: the composition of two validators remembers messages from both the first action and the second action.

```
instance Monoid m => Category (Validator m) where
    id = Validator [] id
    Validator ms act . Validator ms' act' = Validator (ms ++ ms') (act . act')

instance Monoid m => Arrow (Validator m) where
    arr f = Validator [] (arr f)
    first (Validator ms act) = Validator ms (first act)

instance Monoid m => ArrowChoice (Validator m) where
    left (Validator ms act) = Validator ms (left act)
```

All the magic is in the operation that actually lets you report something:

```
reportWhen :: Monoid m => m -> (a -> Bool) -> Validator m a ()
reportWhen m f = Validator [m] (Kleisli $ \a -> when (f a) (tell m))
```

This is the operation that notices when you're about to output a possible message, and makes a note of it. Let's copy your types and show how to code up `checkPerson` as an arrow. I've simplified your messages a little bit, but nothing important is different there -- just less syntactic overhead in the example.

```
type Message = String
data Name = FullName String String | NickName String -- http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/
data Person = Person { name :: Name, age :: Maybe Int }

checkPerson :: Validator Message Person ()
checkPerson = proc person -> do
    case age person of
        Nothing -> returnA -< ()
        Just years -> do
            "negative age"  `reportWhen` (<  0) -< years
            "age too large" `reportWhen` (>200) -< years
    case name person of
        FullName firstName lastName -> do
            "empty first name" `reportWhen` null -< firstName
        NickName nick -> do
            "empty nickname"   `reportWhen` null -< nick
```

I hope you'll agree that this syntax is not *too* far removed from what you originally wrote. Let's see it in action in ghci:

```
> runWriter (runValidator checkPerson (Person (NickName "") Nothing))
((),"empty nickname")
> possibleMessages checkPerson 
["empty nickname","empty first name","age too large","negative age"]
```

Comment: Also, I love how unobtrusively you sneaked that link into there.